# ImageView: OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget on device locked

Tags: android

I recently added three small images to my apps GUI. They are around 40kb in size. Everything is fine until the screen locks on the device. When I unlock I get this error:

OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

I've seen plenty of articles relating to the error but all seems to be for a different reason. I'm not doing anything fancy like downloading from the internet. Just local resources for the UI.

Any suggestions welcome

Thanks

Dann

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[android]bitmap+size+exceeds+VM+budget

Answer (score 0):

If the images are too big, and you are creating many `Bitmaps`, you'll have either to properly scale the `Bitmaps` before usage in code, or the shrink your resource images, if they are included in your project.

Also you have to properly use `bitmap.recycle()` when you no longer use your `Bitmaps`. This means that setting an `Object` which contains an `Bitmap` to `null` or clearing an `ArrayList` of `Bitmaps` won't be enough. You'll first have to iterate over the `Bitmaps` and call `recycle()` and clear then the list.